# Problems Known with CodePen Supporting Flickr?

Tags: css, codepen

Newbie to programming here! I'm completing a project with pretty basic **HTML/CSS** files, and I'm using **Atom** as my editor. Both the HTML and CSS files are validated with no errors, and the page can be previewed fine in both Atom HTML preview, and in Chrome.

I have two images in the HTML file that I uploaded to **Flickr** so that I may submit my project for review via **CodePen**. When I plug in the new `img src` code for **CodePen**, they show up as broken image links.

For example, the below code works fine in Atom HTML as well as Chrome browser Preview (using upticks instead of brackets for ease of viewing post):

```
'img src="lizatdesk.png" class="image" alt="graphic of Liz sitting at her desk"'
```

And this is my link assigned by Flickr and plugged into CodePen - results in a broken link (using upticks instead of brackets for ease of viewing post):

```
'img src="https://flic.kr/p/QFZVZp" class="image" alt="graphic of Liz sitting at her desk"'
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://flic.kr/p/QFZVZp` does not point to an image. It points to an HTML page. To show a photo stored on Flickr you must use the URL of the photo; see this [FAQ](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/sln15714.html). In your case, that's `https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/255/31957771213_4ed09e18b1_o.png`. And per the Flickr terms of use you must also provide a link back to Flickr.